# How should I set this project up in .NET?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, asp.net-mvc-3, workflow

I have a unique set of processes that all need to be automated.

**We receive very inconsistent data from our customer so this requires a lot of responses from not very computer literate users. I'de go with console if it wasn't for that.**

That data needs to be transformed and then combined using a few different processes.

I need to create an application that can only be accessed from one person at a time (we don't want to have multiple people building the same data).

All processes can be run on one machine.

A basic outline is the following...

1. Get all of the zip files from our customers FTP
2. Unzip all of these files into the specified directory
3. Take this data and verify it's surface level integrity
4. Transform the data to a new format
5. Import to the database
6. Build documents based on the data

I know how to write each of these functions, **my question is more: should I do this in MVC3 with AJAX updates, WPF, windows forms, or straight asp.net?** I know all of them, I just can't think of which fits this linear processing scheme. The user also needs constant updating of progress on each file so any of the asp.net derivatives get tricky with ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend just making a console application.  Do you need an interface?

Comment: My only hesitation is, right now these processes are distinct. I've written a series of batch files and winforms tools. It was a naive approach to have them all separate and requires a technical person to run. Now the new requirement is that it be runnable by anyone with very limited computer experience. That's my only hesitation to console, it would possibly kill that requirement from my boss.

Comment: Note: this would be easy for anyone, except the data is incredibly unreliable so it requires a bit of intervention from the user. That would mean some console responses from less than par users.

Comment: I think trying to get non-technical users to perform a technical operation (even through a windows interface) is asking for trouble.

Comment: Ha, agreed, though I don't think that will be my response to my boss! I think certain interfaces would be nicer for them. All of my mentioned interfaces can provider equal(ish) experiences. I'm just trying to figure out which one fits my scenario best.

Comment: ok, my boss walked in and I took the opportunity to ask him to read this. He said he doesn't want "trouble" so go ahead and do the console. Thanks! haha. Now it's press 1. if this broke, press 2. if this broke...

Answer (score 1):

Two options: a console application to be launched as a scheduled task, or a Windows Service.

Answer (score 1):

If everything is automated I would create a windows service to do everything. By doing so you'll also prevent the application from being run by more than once simultaneously (unless you install it on several computers).

Comment: It's automated if the data is perfect. It's almost never perfect and requires a lot of intervention when, say a csv file is missing a column, etc.

Comment: Create two folders for the application. One for data that should be processed and one for invalid data. Send an email each time something is put in the "invalid" folder. Let a technician fix it and add it to the "process" folder again when the file have been corrected.

Comment: The time that you'll put on a GUI is waste of time. Tell your boss that it's better that you use that time to fix typical data errors instead. More automation = less spent money. The non-technical users can't fix the problems anyway.